# No sectoids to capture

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I think my game has reached a point where it can't progress any further.

I am about 10 months in and I have researched everything. Early in the game though I never caught a sectoid, the troops were too zealous on over watch. There have been no sectoids for months and I can't research past the interrogation.

I've caught a thin man and an overseer but haven't been given the opportunity to interrogate or research them. I am assuming that I need to do the sectoid first.

Am I stuck and need to start over or should I continue to hold out and hope they show up in a future mission?

Comment: Do you have an alien containment? You should be able to interrogate any alien you've captured alive and contained.

Comment: Yes, I've built a containment cell. I believe that is a prerequisites for the arcthrower.

Comment: @NASlacker Building an alien containment base facility is not one of the prerequisites for the arcthrower, but researching the containment facility is a requirement for researching the arcthrower. Are you sure you've built the base facility, and not just researched it?

Comment: yea, you don't HAVE to capture a sectoid, any alien will do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't **have** to interrogate all the aliens. If they are not available for interrogation, and you have an Alien Containment it's because you've interrogated them in the past and forgot about it. You can see all the steps needed for progression here: [What are all of the priority missions needed to complete the game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87651/what-are-all-of-the-priority-missions-needed-to-complete-the-game).

You only need to interrogate the sectoid for the full research achievement. It doesn't prevent you from advancing and finishing the game.

You can see here: [What does the full research tree look like?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87637/what-does-the-full-research-tree-look-like) it doesn't "block" any other research.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *have* to capture a sectoid to finish the game. You only have to capture and interrogate *any* life alien to trigger the "capture an outsider" goal.

When you have built (not just researched) an alien containment facility You should be able to interrogate the thin man. The outsider isn't technically interrogated:

> when you take one down with the arc thrower, it transforms into an alien artifact called "Outsider Shard" which is then researched like any other alien artifact. I don't know if you even need the containment facility for that.

I don't know if you can research the outsider before you got the mission telling you to do so, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a list of which aliens you've already interrogated by going to Research > View Tech Credits. Each Tech Credit will be earned by one alien interrogation, and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing you need to capture a live sectoid for is plasma pistols.  I didn't capture a live alien until after they stopped spawning so i missed out on them